# jQuery add substract dates from current date with navigation

Tags: jquery, date

I'm having a little problem updating data-attributes when dynamically changing  dates using a simple navigation:

Here is html:

```
<button id="prev" data-date="2016, 04, 10">Previous</button>
<button id="next" data-date="2016, 04, 03">Next</button>
```

here is javascript:

```
    function addDays(noOfDays, date) {
        var origTimezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
        date = new Date(date.getTime() + (noOfDays * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
        var offsetDiff = (date.getTimezoneOffset() - origTimezoneOffset) * 60 * 1000;
        date = new Date(date.getTime() + offsetDiff);

        var month = (date.getMonth() + 1);
        var day = (date.getDate());
        if (month < 10) {
            month = '0' + month;
        }
        if (day < 10) {
            day = '0' + day;
        }
        var formatted = date.getFullYear() + ', ' + month + ', ' + day;
        return formatted;
    }
```

and here is onclick event:

```
    $("#prev, #next").on('click', function() {
        var string = $(this).attr('data-date');

        if ($(this).attr('id') === "next") {
            $(this).attr("data-date", addDays(7, new Date(string)));
            $("#prev").attr('data-date', addDays(-7, new Date(string)));
        } else {
            $(this).attr('data-date', addDays(-7, new Date(string)));
            $("#next").attr('data-date', addDays(7, new Date(string)));
        }
    });
```

Everything works perfectly fine in FF and Chrome, but IE ans Safari returns 
NaN, NaN, NaN

I have created jsbin as well : https://jsbin.com/puvakivika/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Date format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you need to convert the string "2016, 04, 10" to "2016/04/10" before to procede.

For more details on date format see [Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

In your case, you need to use a simple string replace: .replace(/, /g, '-')

For data atribute instead of using .attr use [.data( key, value )](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data1)

```js
function addDays(noOfDays, date) {
  var origTimezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
  date = new Date(date.getTime() + (noOfDays * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
  var offsetDiff = (date.getTimezoneOffset() - origTimezoneOffset) * 60 * 1000;
  date = new Date(date.getTime() + offsetDiff);

  var month = (date.getMonth() + 1);
  var day = (date.getDate());
  if (month < 10) {
    month = '0' + month;
  }
  if (day < 10) {
    day = '0' + day;
  }
  var formatted = date.getFullYear() + ', ' + month + ', ' + day;
  return formatted;
}

$(function () {
  $("#prev, #next").on('click', function(e) {
    var string = $(this).attr('data-date').replace(/, /g, '-');

    if ($(this).attr('id') === "next") {
      $(this).attr("data-date", addDays(7, new Date(string)));
      $("#prev").attr('data-date', addDays(-7, new Date(string)));
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-date', addDays(-7, new Date(string)));
      $("#next").attr('data-date', addDays(7, new Date(string)));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="prev" data-date="2016, 04, 10">Previous</button>
<button id="next" data-date="2016, 04, 03">Next</button>
```